# scheduled bash script : how to transfer a file from HTTPS web server to FTP server

Tags: bash, ftp, file-transfer, wget, curl

I need to automate a task that downloads an XML file on a https:// web server (with authentification) and upload it on an FTP server (with another authentification).

So I think the best approach is to use CURL (or WGET) to download the file and lftp to upload !?

But I don't know how to script it in .sh file to program it sith cron (every thursday at 8 AM).

Have you got an example ?

**EDIT**

Example of file to download :
`https://www.domain.ltd/.../export.aspx?dt=07.08.2017` (dd.mm.YYYY format)

Example of filename in FTP server while uploaded :
`export_07.08.2017.xml`

Answer (score 2):

Your question composes actually of three questions:
1) How to download a file (with auth)
2) How to upload a file (with auth)
3) How to schedule a CRON job

My first question is how do you want to store the id/passwd

**ad 1)**  You can use both `curl` and `wget` depending on what is better for your use case.  I recommend reading excellent post by Daniel Stenberg [curl vs Wget](https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html) to understand the differences (a quick summary - `curl` is more developer friendly and is also a library a `wget` is a command).

I'm recommending using certificates without user/passwd as such would be visible to everyone having your id or group.

In my example, I'll use `curl` and certificate:
`curl --cert certificate_file.pem https://example.com/example.xml`

**ad 2)** To upload a file
`curl -T example.xml --cert certificate_file.pem ftps://ftp.server.com/remotedir/`

**ad 3)** Cron format:

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
    0        2          12             *                *            /usr/bin/find
```

You only `crontab -e` to edit your crontab file.  Other ways can lead to file corruption.

If you want to run your file every Thursday at 8AM do it the following way:
`0 8 1-31 1-12 4 /path/your_script.sh` or you can do it with `*`: `0 8 * * 4 /path/your_script.sh` .

If you want to read more do it at: [Cron and Crontab usage and examples](https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html)

Now put it together:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 is your command line input (e.g. example.xml)
file_download=$1
file_upload=$2

actual_download="curl --cert certificate_file.pem https://example.com/$file_download"

eval $actual_download

if [ -e "$file_upload" ] then
  actual_upload="curl -T $file_upload --cert certificate_file.pem ftps://ftp.server.com/remotedir"
  eval $actual_upload
else
  echo "The $file_upload does not exist!"
fi
```

You would then execute the file:
`your_script.sh /path/example_download.xml /path/example_upload.xml`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. For Cron it's all ok. for download I have an https://www... access with user and password. On FTP it's user and password authentification too.

Filename is date of the day : https://www.domain.ltd/.../services/lqjxmlexport/export.aspx?dt=07.08.2017 (dd.mm.YYYY format)

Comment: @Meloman: Please do :).  I always recommend using certificates as it is way more secure and nobody can "steal" your credentials from plaintext.  If you want to use curl with credentials `curl -u username:password https://example.com`.  If it answers your question please mark it, thank you.

Comment: Yes, of course but we have no choice to use what provider of the xml gives to us, and it's simple authentification ! Even if I find it stupid since SSL is enough to keep the data confidential. Data that are not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

With help of @djsmiley2k on chat and @tukan here... here is my working approach :

```
#!/bin/bash

#source 
host_from="https://some_web_server/.../export"
file_download=export.aspx?dt=`date +%d.%m.%Y`
user_from="www_user"
pass_from="www_password"

#download file form web server
xml_file="curl -u '$user_from:$pass_from' $host_from/$file_download"

# destination
host_to="some_ftp_server/httpdocs/subfolder/.../Export"
file_upload=`date +%d.%m.%Y`.xml
user_to="ftp_user"
pass_to="ftp_password"

#upload file to FTP server
xml_upload="curl -T $file_upload -u '$user_to:$pass_to' $host_to/$file_upload"
```

Main issue was to escape user and password vars with single quotes.